# Why I can't execute the video hosted on my godaddy account?

Tags: html

When I try to execute the video from external url

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>

<source src="videos/r.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

it works fine but it does not work when it is hosted on my hosting account I don't know what is going wrong.any help will be  appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because we are not GoDaddy support. (And to be honest, the question is also I indecipherable).

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools networking tab and see if you get a 200 response for the video.